# MvvmLight too much messages

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am switching two Views. after message sending from `Messenger.Default.Send<Message>(new Message {LoadingIndication="Loaded" },"Token");` It's reciving two message's because it create's OneViewModel two times first time in BinaryMultiViewModel second into OneView. But i need only one message. I can not remove something because in first case it should not switch in second it should show data.

For example

MultiView.cs

```
namespace Test.ViewModel
{
class BinaryMultiViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    readonly static OneViewModel OneViewModel = new OneViewModel();

    readonly static FourViewModel FourViewModel = new FourViewModel();

    private ViewModelBase currentMultiViewModel;

    public BinaryMultiViewModel()
    {
        currentMultiViewModel = BinaryMultiViewModel.OneViewModel;
    }

    public ViewModelBase CurrentMultiViewModel
    {

        get
        {
            return currentMultiViewModel;
        }

        set
        {
            if (currentMultiViewModel == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            currentMultiViewModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentMultiViewModel");
        }
    }
}
}
```

MultiView.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding CurrentMultiViewModel}" />
</Grid>
```

OneViewModel.cs:

```
namespace Test.ViewModel
{
public class OneViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public OneViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<Message>(this,"Token", FromMultiModel);
    }
    private void FromMultiModel(Message input)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(input.LoadingIndication);
    }
}
}
```

OneView.cs

```
namespace Test.Views
{
public partial class OneView : UserControl
{
    public OneView()
    {
        DataContext = new OneViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
}
```

App.xaml:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:OneViewModel}">
    <views:OneView/>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:FourViewModel}">
    <views:FourView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Why do you create ViewModel in your ViewModel then ? Put it to ViewModelLocator.

Comment: Witouht creating ViewModel in ViewModel i should not be enable to bind datatemplate with View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create `OneViewModel` in `OneView`'s ctor and assing it to datacontext.

The `OneViewModel` instance is created in `BinaryMultiViewModel` and when you set it to `ContentControl` using databinding and DataTempate with `OneView` usercontrol is chosen, then `OneViewModel` is set automatically as datacontext of `OneView`

just remove the line `DataContext = new OneViewModel();` and it should work.